# How to recover the existing table in mysql navicate

Tags: mysql, database

Due to some unknown reason I was not able to see the DB in mysql navicate. Mysql command line was not displaying the DB too.
So I have repaired the mysql instance. But still its not showing old DB. I have created a new DB with same name but when I am creating the tables it is showing table already exists. How to recover the existing table? I do not have backup files too?

Comment: try to login in mysql command line using `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: Did it work? @neeraj simon

Comment: When I am opening mysql command line its directly asking for password without user name?

Comment: `mysql -u root -p` if you try with this then username is `root` and after pressing ENTER password will be asked.

Comment: If you didn't set up any password then just ENTER.

Comment: after the above procedure i gave command show databases. It is not showing old database.

Comment: would you please check if the ../mysql/data directory contain which databases (in the file system)?

Comment: There is no file with .sql extension in the above mentioned location